# Not all work-items being used opencl

Tags: c++, linux, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

so I'm able to compile and execute my kernel, the problem is that only two work-items are being used. I'm basically trying to fill up a float array[8] with {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. So this is a very simple hello world application. Bellow is my kernel.

```
// Highly simplified to demonstrate
__kernel void rnd_float32_matrix (
  __global float * res
) {
  uint idx = get_global_id(0);

  res[idx] = idx;
}
```

I then create and execute the kernel with the following code...

```
   // Some more code

   cl::Program program(context, sources, &err);
   program.build(devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   cl::Kernel kernel(program, "rnd_float32_matrix", &err);
   kernel.setArg(0, src_d);

   cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0], 0, &err);

   cl::Event event;

   err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
      kernel,
      cl::NullRange,
      cl::NDRange(8),
      // I've tried cl::NDRange(8) as well
      cl::NDRange(1),
      NULL,
      &event
    );

   event.wait();

   err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(
      // This is:
      //   cl::Buffer src_d(
      //     context,
      //     CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
      //     mem_size,
      //     src_h,
      //     &err);
      src_d,
      CL_TRUE,
      0,
      8,
      // This is float * src_h = new float[8];
      src_h);

   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    std::cout << src_h[i] << std::endl;
   }
```

I may not show it in the code, but I also do select a gpu device and using context.getInfo(..) it shows I'm using my NVidia GTX 770M card which shows 1024, 1024, 64 work-items available in dimensions 0, 1 and 2. When this array prints I keep getting... 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. I've also tried setting res[idx] = 5, and I get... 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. So it seems that only two give work-items are actually being used. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess, you simplified your program too much. `res[idx] = inSeed` is unclear, as the initialization of `inSeed` is not shown.

Comment: Try creating `src_d` with `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` flag instead of `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY`.

Comment: @Christian: Thanks it's supposed to be res[idx] = idx;

Comment: @sgarizvi: CL_MEM_READ_WRITE didn't wok for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command to read the data back from the device is only reading 8 bytes, which is two floats:

```
err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(
  src_d,
  CL_TRUE,
  0,
  8, // <- This is the number of bytes, not the number of elements!
  // This is float * src_h = new float[8];
  src_h);
```

To read 8 floats, you would need to do this:

```
err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(
  src_d,
  CL_TRUE,
  0,
  8 * sizeof(cl_float),
  // This is float * src_h = new float[8];
  src_h);
```

Comment: Haha, ya I know! I messed up and it I figured it out on my later, but that certainly was the issue! I'm still thinking in terms of the scripting world. Thanks, for taking the time!